# Visual Studio Code and Clangd include errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

I have a including problems when trying to use clangd.

Heres the latest i've tried:

- Clean install of VS Code 1.86.1
- Install Clangd from the VS Code extensions
- Configure Clangd extension settings:

  - clangd: Path
  - clangd: Arguments

    - `--compile-commands-dir...`
    - `-j=6`
- `F1 + clangd: Restart language server`

I've tested it with these:
Test main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "IT WORKS\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Test CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

project(test)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
)
```

Which I have initialized with `mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../ && make && ./test`
The program does the "IT WORKS" cout in the terminal right but VS Code is showing clang errors with `<iostream>` and `std` for not recognizing them.

Comment: So you are talking about Intellisense errors / red squiggles? Do you have the CMakeTools extension installed?

Comment: Yes! The include and the std are both underlined with red showing errors. Never had this problem before clangd. I have CMake by TWXS and CMakeTools by Microsoft installed.

Comment: Please attach [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) to the question, they contain information likely to be relevant for figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this from another stack overflow post and it did the trick:

"I spoke to a colleague who told me that gcc-12 was included in ubuntu 22.04 an created some mess with clang. To solve the issue, I did

> sudo apt install g++-12

and now it works well."